# How to change system image for particular AVD in Android studio 2.3.3 ? [as we can't launch standalone AVD manager on this version]

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I have download 3 system images for Android Oreo
[as shown in picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSlhx.png) in SDK manager

[image]

But when I check in **Choose System Image** from AVD manager in Android Studio, those installed all images are not shown (only Google APIs system image is shown) .

I checked in all of the following tabs [snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkbOK.png)

[image]

- Recommended images
- x86 images
- Other images

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

To change system image for particular AVD :-

1. Copy desired system-image name (just name) from

> sdk folder > system-images > android-X [mine was **google_apis** and **google_apis_playstore**]

If folder is empty then first you need to download system image from sdk manager

2. Go to AVD manager from android studio.
3. Right click on AVD you want to change and click Show On Disk
4. It will open file explorer when AVD files are located
5. Open config file in wordpad (or notepad)
6. Look for `image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-26\<paste-system-image-name-here>\x86\`

> image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86\

is replaced by

> image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-26\google_apis_playstore\x86\

Now emulator running API 26 is running correctly.

Comment: I tried this method and while it did update the emulator, it ended up wiping away previous data. In the future, I would just create a new emulator since I would like to preserve data.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the AVD and select a system image by clicking on the `Choose...` button in the third row